# What is the computational complexity of an equation composed of $2m^2$ divisions and $2m^2$ addition of $2n$ additions?

Tags: complex-analysis, computational-complexity

I want to calculate the computational complexity in term of the big (O). My equation is:

[image]

Where the $S^+$ and $S^-$ are calculated as follows:

[image]

Where $\triangle_TOPSIS$ It composed of $2m^2$ divisions and $2m^2$ addition. While $S^+$ and $S^-$ composed of  $2n$ additions and  $2n$ multiplication. My question is that how can I write the computational complexity for $\triangle_{TOPSIS}$ ?

It is O($2m^2$ $\times$  $2m^2$  $\times$ $2n \times 2n$ )? or
O($2m^2$ $+$  $2m^2$  $+$ $2n + 2n$ )

Comment: If you’ve computed the $a_s=\frac{S_s^-}{S_s^++S_s^-}$ the final term can be computed on $O(M\log M)$ time by sorting the $a_s?$

Comment: However, your algorithm takes the sum of the steps, not the product. You don’t need to calculate $S_1^+$ more than once.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, so the final complexity is $O(2m^2)$ ?

Comment: Well, $O(4m^2+4n)=O(m^2+n).$ Unless we know that, say, $n=O(m^2),$ we can’t eliminate the $n.$ For example, when $n=m^3.$